# bash: Can you limit expansion when using pathname expansion?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have the following directories:

- `dir/one`
- `dir/two`
- `dir/three`
- `dir/four`

I can use a bash pathname expansion construct like this: `ls dir/{one,three}`
This will expand as `dir/one` and `dir/three`

Is there a way to say "all but" ... ?
Something like `dir/{*,!three,!four}` or `dir/{*,^three,^four}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *ignore* option with -I or --ignore=PATTERN

```
ls --ignore=dir/three --ignore=dir/two
```